# A function that pops the element in the string

Tags: javascript, function, arraylist

Im currently trying to make a function that pops the last element from a list/string, but cant seem to make it work. I can make it work without a function by using:

var sport = ["fodbold", "håndbold", "golf"];

console.log(sport.pop());

But i need it to be a function. Also if possible, i want it to return a message if the string/array is empty

Thanks in advance!

Comment: const pop = arr => {if (arr.length > 0) arr.pop() else throw new Error('Array Empty')};

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var sport = ["fodbold", "håndbold", "golf"];


function getLast(arr) {
  return !arr.length ? 'Array is empty' : arr.pop();
}

console.log(getLast(sport));
console.log(getLast(sport));
console.log(getLast(sport));
console.log(getLast(sport));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sport = ["fodbold", "håndbold", "golf"];
const func = () => {
    if (sport.length > 0) {
        return sport.pop();
    } else {
        return "List is Empty"
    }
}
func();
```